# Join based on ID and closest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table 1 which contains phone calls (for every `CustomerID` there is at most one PhoneCall per day):

```
ActicityID  CustomerID   PhoneDate
1           A            2019-11-01
2           A            2019-12-01
3           A            2019-12-20
4           B            2019-11-01
5           B            2019-11-20
6           C            2019-11-03
7           D            2019-11-03
8           D            2019-12-01
9           E            2019-11-05
10          F            2019-11-01
```

Table 2 which contains Orders (`OrdDate` is the date when the order was placed and `BillingDate` is the date when the order was charged)

```
CustomerID  OrdDate      BillingDate
A           2019-12-03   2019-12-04
A           2019-12-21   2019-12-21
B           2019-11-03   2019-11-10
D           2019-12-02   2019-12-02
F           2019-11-02   2019-11-02
```

I want to join the tables. The joined table should have the same number of rows as Table 1.
So basically I want to know if there was order after a phone call. The problem is that if just join on `CustomerID` I get an `OrdDat` and a `BillingDate` for every customer who has ever made an order. For example Customer A made an order after the call on 2019-12-01 and after the call on the 2019-12-20 but not after the first call.

So my desired output would be

```
ActicityID  CustomerID   PhoneDate    OrdDate     BillingDate 
1           A            2019-11-01   NULL        NULL
2           A            2019-12-01   2019-12-03  2019-12-04
3           A            2019-12-20   2019-12-21  2019-12-21
4           B            2019-11-01   2019-11-03  2019-11-10
5           B            2019-11-20   NULL        NULL
6           C            2019-11-03   NULL        NULL
7           D            2019-11-03   NULL        NULL
8           D            2019-12-01   2019-12-02  2019-12-02
9           E            2019-11-05   NULL        NULL
10          F            2019-11-01   2019-11-02  2019-11-02
```

I think I need to join on CustomerID and the closest date between PhoneDate and OrdDate but my SQL knowledge is quite limited and I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: what have you tried? did you have a look at the different types of joins and how to do them?

Comment: You should use left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do what you want by using `lead()` to get the next phone date and then just joining:

```
select a.*, b.orddate, b.billdate
from (select a.*,
             lead(phonedate) over (partition by customerid order by phonedate) as next_pd
      from a
     ) a left join
     b
     on b.customerid = a.customerid and
        b.orddate >= a.phonedate and
        (b.orddate < a.next_pd or a.next_pd is null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get a lot of duplicates when I try this (Table A has ~ 52000 rows, I stopped the query after 1000000 rows)

Comment: @dyel . . . I missed that you also want to join on the customer id.  That will fix the duplication problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still get a few duplicates (~100 out of the 52000 observations) but that's probably because of other columns I didn't mention in my question.

Comment: Out of interest, @GordonLinoff, are there any advantages with your answer over my version below?  I tend to eschew such functionality over more straightforward SQL, unless there's a distinct advantage to using it.

Comment: @Paul . . . `lead()` is more "straighforward" than correlated subqueries (being standard and more concise).  It also provides more opportunities for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a sub-query to limit the other table, referencing the `TOP 1` associated date record...

```
SELECT
    ActivityID, 
    CustomerID, 
    PhoneDate,
   (SELECT TOP (1) 
        OrderDate
    FROM 
        dbo.CustomerBilling AS b
    WHERE 
        a.PhoneDate < OrderDate AND 
        a.CustomerID = CustomerID
    ORDER BY OrderDate) AS BillingDate
FROM 
    dbo.Activity AS a
```